# How to pass variable to new page?

Tags: php, ajax, variables, post, get

I have a question.

- It is possible to pass variable to a new page to a new page... without method `GET`. **But it's visible.**
- Is it possible to pass variable to a new page to a new page... with method `POST` without a form ?
- Is it possible to get variable to a new page with `ajax` ?

I need to pass ID from a page to another page to another page... without that the visitor sees the variable in URL.

**EDIT :**  Yes, I tought to session but when I go to home, I need to delete this session. Is it really a good idea to use session ?

**EDIT :**  Which is the best way ? `COOKIE` OR `SESSION`

Thanks

Comment: @Col Example : 1,2,3,...,12,20

Comment: What is matter of this variable? What matter it represents? is it page id, goods id, user id?

Comment: why do you want to hide it then? Questions are "products of stackoverflow". Nobody have an idea of hiding them.

Comment: It depends on the circumstances What certain method to choose. Why don't you ask whole question instead of only little part of it? There are general solutions for general tasks. You'll be supplied with the best one if you'll be little more talkative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [***sessions***](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses. This enables you to build more customized applications and increase the appeal of your web site. All information is in the [Session reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) section.

The first page can put the ID in the session and the other page can retrieve it.

Comment: Yes, I tought to session but when I go to home, I need to delete this session. Is it really a good idea to use session ?

Comment: @Steffi: What's wrong with deleting the session? Sessions are for persisting data between requests, like e.g. a cart in a eShop. And this seems to be what you want to do (persisting data, not the cart ;))

Comment: Yes ! Exactly ! Thanks. I'll try it. (What is the best way ? `COOOKIE` or `SESSION` ?)

Comment: If you don't want it visible to the user, then use sessions. And if you want to delete the session you can use either `session_destroy();`, to completely destroy the session. Or use `unset($_SESSION['my_var']);` to remove a particular key from the session.

Comment: @Steffi: Well sessions work only with `$_SESSION`. `$_COOKIES` is for cookies you have set. Cookies are set at the client so theoretically they can be changed by the client and you cannot trust them.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take a look at [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp)

This allows you to set a variable like so: `$_SESSION['my_var'] = $my_Var;` You will then be able to pass this variable around the different pages. You return the variable by calling `$_SESSION['my_var']`.

Remember though, that on each page you use sessions you need to have `session_start();` at the top of each page.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies is what you are looking for. You can set the page id in cookie value, and then using `$_COOKIE`, retrieve it. Though, it might not work if using multiple/different hosts.

Also, using AJAX, you can also make POST requests along with GET. Frameworks like jQuery, Mootools, etc. allow this easily.

Comment: What is the best way ? `COOOKIE` or `SESSION` ?

Comment: Though I am not an expert, but as per my knowledge, session is always generated by the system, for cookie, its on to you, you set the name, you set the value.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same server, you can use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp) but if it's across two different servers, you can post via [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

Beside using sessions, you can write the variable to the database first.